# A Select All (filetered/unfiltered) rows button in Jquery Datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

How do I create a select all checkbox in the jquery datatable plugin I am using in my application. Is there a plugin for this feature in the datatbles. I am not able to find any such thing in my search.

```
$("#button_select_all").click(function () {

                $(allSamplesTable.fnGetFilteredNodes()).find(':checkbox').each(function () {
                    $this = $(this);
                    $this.attr('checked', 'checked');

                   for (var i = 0; i < _sampleTableExports.length; i++) {
                        if (_sampleTableExports[i]["Id"] == $(this).val()) {
                            _sampleTableExports.splice(i, 1);
                            return true;
                        }
                   }
                   _sampleTableExports.push({ "Name": $(this).attr("name"), "Id": $(this).val() });
                });

            });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Any code examples? Probably wont get many replies until you post some

Comment: @JayRizzi I have edited my question with my current code for the select button for the datatable plugin.